# Which command line software tools are required to mine litecoin

Tags: litecoin, ubuntu, linux

I have compiled litecoin core and am currently running litecoind which is downloading the blockchain.

What other command-line tools do I need in order to mine litecoin without a GUI? And what are the other prerequesites (aside from a beefy rig with lots of graphics cards etc)? Can I just create a wallet and set the daemon running? Does the daemon mine coins or do I need to use litecoin-cli to instruct the daemon as to the location of my wallet etc?

I can't seem to find any decent command line guides - most seem to be for cgminer or litecoin-qt

Comment: As with Bitcoin, it is not viable or worth your time to mine with a computer and hasn't been for a long time. Mining has moved to specialized ASIC processors which can do the job faster and much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You have miners on command line like [sgminer](https://github.com/veox/sgminer) or [cgminer](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer). You can use this with a GUI but it is not a requirement.

You can find usage guide on previous link.
Exemple for sgminer. After you build it and install it, you simply have to execute this command to lunch mining :

```
sgminer -o http://pool:port -u username -p password
```

Replace :

- **pool** by adresse of your pool
- **port** by the port of your mining pool
- **username** and **password** by your pool login.

If you want more information check official github of these projects